# nifi unpack processor - unexpected record signature

Tags: apache-nifi

I am facing issue with the unpack processor. Screenshot attached.
If anyone could help me would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an error `java.util.zip.ZipException: Unexpected record signature`

Seems your flow file is not a zip or it is corrupted